# AWS RDSDataService query not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

I'm trying to use RDSDataService to query an Aurora Serverless database. When I'm trying to query, my lambda just times out (I've set it up to 5 minutes just to make sure it isn't a problem with that). I have 1 record in my database and when I try to query it, I get no results, and neither the error or data flows are called. I've verified executeSql is called by removing the dbClusterOrInstanceArn from my params and it throw the exception for not having it.

I have also run SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST in the query editor to see if the queries were still running and they are not. I've given the lambda both the AmazonRDSFullAccess and AmazonRDSDataFullAccess policies without any luck either. You can see by the code below, i've already tried what was recommended in issue #2376.

Not that this should matter, but this lambda is triggered by a Kinesis event trigger.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const RDS = new AWS.RDSDataService({apiVersion: '2018-08-01', region: 'us-east-1'})
  for (record of event.Records) {
    const payload = JSON.parse(new Buffer(record.kinesis.data, 'base64').toString('utf-8'));
    const data = compileItem(payload);
    const params = {
      awsSecretStoreArn: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:149070771508:secret:xxxxxxxxx,
      dbClusterOrInstanceArn: 'arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:149070771508:cluster:xxxxxxxxx',
      sqlStatements: `select * from MY_DATABASE.MY_TABLE`
      // database: 'MY_DATABASE'
    }
    console.log('calling executeSql');
    RDS.executeSql(params, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
        callback(error, null);
      } else {
        console.log('data', data);
        callback(null, { success: true })
      }
    });
  }
}
```

EDIT: We've run the command through the aws cli and it returns results.

EDIT 2: I'm able to connect to it using the `mysql2` package and connecting to it through the URI, so it's defiantly an issue with either the `aws-sdk` or how I'm using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the RDS had to be crated in a VPC, in which the Lambda's were not in

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs excution is not waiting for the result that's why process exit before completing the request.

use mysql library https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-mysql
OR
use context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop =false

Comment: So apparently, when your RDS is in a VPC, the lambda must also be in that VPC

Comment: Yes offcourse. Unless you define it EIP and make RDS public from VPC.